# How are package names determined in java, why "com" as a root?

Tags: flash, directory, directory-structure

I tried googling this but can't find anything. I'm just curious as to why we use the folder name 'com' as the root directory? what does it stand for? computer? haha. thanks

Comment: "com" could be from ".com" or short for "common" or it could be something else.  More context please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java, the convention is to name packages prefixed by the reverse of the domain name of the package provider. For example, the package "foobar" developed by microsoft (which owns "microsoft.com") might be named "com.microsoft.foobar". If your company owns the domain "fantastic.net", you would name the package "net.fantastic.foobar".

The packages are organized on disk related to their name, so "net.fantastic.foobar" would be in the folder "com/fantastic/foobar".

This is just a simple, low-overhead way to prevent two companies from developing packages that have the same name.

FWIW, the "com" in a domain name context stands for "commercial", as in "related to commerce". [Wikipedia has more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com) if you are curious.

Answer (score 8):

Standard practice when naming **packages**, in order to avoid collisions, is to name them after a **domain** that you own, in reverse order.  So if your company's website was `betterwidgets.com`, you would almost certainly put your files in a `com.betterwidgets.*` package.

Java (and probably other languages) impose that the directory structure needs to conform to the package hierarchy (even though it's non-hierarchical, go figure) and so in this case, all the source files would be under "com" directory, then a "betterwidgets" subdirectory within that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a domain name with the components in reverse order.

Comment: what do you mean its a domain name? im talking about in flash for example it seems standard to have the root directory folder name to be called com. so you would have like com.ui.whatever etc.

Comment: The OP is talking about package names, not domain names.

Answer (score 1):

Generally ".com" stands for a commercial solution. In this case I suppose that the package is part of a commercial API.